# Python Missing installed Modules

Tags: python, pip, package

I have apparently never installed packages using pip before, and so this is causing me quite a bit of dificulty. Using this method https://realpython.com/pysimplegui-python/ I tried installing the PySimpleGUI package. However, when I go to import it in my code `import PySimpleGUI as sg` I get the error message "No module named PySimpleGUI" I've checked in powershell and despite [it apparently being here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMq0r.png), I am still apparently unable to access it in my pycharm. I've mostly gathered that my python is somehow checking a different folder for installed packages, so I don't know if I should install it in a different folder or change the path. Or some other solution.

Comment: Python has a global environment, into which you can install packages and allows you to create virtual environments into which you can install packages that are only available to applications in that environment. From what you are describing, it sounds like you installed a package into one environment, while your PyCharm project is using another environment. Check the 'interpreter'  in your project settings.

Comment: You can access your Python Interpreter by pressing `ctrl + alt + s` - that is where you'll be able to manage associated packages and libraries, you can manually add the package as well.